# React native asyncstorage get data

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I am using componentWillMount in react-native to get data from API. But when I tried to get the token stored while login. It cannot work. I have no idea whats the problem/

```
componentWillMount(){

        let token = this.getData
        fetch('http://192.168.0.125:8887/api/auth/activities/index',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '. token,
            },
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())

        .then((res) => {
            //console.log(res)

        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('Error: ', e))
    }

    getData = async () => {
        let token =''
        try{
            token = AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token')
            console.log(token)
        }catch (error) {
            console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
        }
        return token
    }
```

Comment: use await ```await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the api call inside ComponentWillMount.
Do that inside ComponentDidMount.
And for your problem - 
Try await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token') because AsyncStorage is a promise.

or you can do

```
componentDidMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token').then(this.getData)
}



getData=(token)=>{
   fetch('http://192.168.0.125:8887/api/auth/activities/index',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token,
        },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())

    .then((res) => {
        //console.log(res)

    })
    .catch((e) => console.log('Error: ', e))
    }
```

Comment: oh great, I get the token in getData, but I can't call the token in the header of fetch? what is the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by call the token?

Comment: 'Authorization': 'Bearer '. token,

Comment: im trying to put the token into the header

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: the token inside the header didnt work as the what i get at the top.

Comment: Do this.... 'Authorization': 'Bearer '  token,

Remove the dot

Comment: cannot remove the token. If remove it will return a syntax error

Comment: oh, I got the prob dy. shd be + but not .
btw tq for ur help.

Comment: yea sorry i forgot to add + there ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

well, AsyncStorage.getItem() is a promise, so you need to use await to get the token before console.log.

`const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token')`

Comment: Oh yea, now i get the token, but how can i use it in componentWillMount? Can what i did work?